# including workling gem causes server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, workling

I am new to rails so I don't really know how to diagnose this problem. I am attemting to use workling for some background tasks, however I have run into a problem. When I include the workling gem in my Gemfile then running "bundle install." I get the following error when running "rails s". Googleing this error does mention updating gem, however I installed ruby and gem using rvm this morning so I doubt that is the problem.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'workling', '~> 0.4.9.9'
```

Error:

```
$ rails s
/home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/workling-0.4.9.9/lib/workling.rb:16:in `<class:Hash>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/workling-0.4.9.9/lib/workling.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/usr1/rock/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/usr1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some googleing and have decided to use another gem. You can see the answer that helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5930407/537363).